# Finding the length of a list in a list of lists, code is displaying the incorrect length even though I'm using len()

Tags: python

I have created a list of lists (shown below). The strings are 6 characters long, but len is returning 1 instead of 6 and I can not figure out why.
[problem code and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1YjN.png)

```
Motifs = [['AACGTA'],
          ['CCCGTT'],
          ['CACCTT'],
          ['GGATTA'],
          ['TTCCGG']]

#print(Motifs)
#count = {"A":[],"C":[],"G":[],"T":[]}
#print(count)
stringlenght = Motifs[0]
print(stringlenght)
k = len(stringlenght)
print(k)
#k should be 6 but is printing as 1   
n = len('AACGTA')
print(n)
#n which is the same as Motifs[0] prints properly as 6
```

Comment: Use a step-by-step debugger to see what each variable contains

Comment: First, you have a tuple of lists (this does not matter as much in your case). The length of the tuple is six: it has six lists in it. The length of each list is one: each has a single string in it. The length of the strings is six: each has each characters in it. You are measuring the wrong thing.

Comment: "#n which is the same as Motifs[0] prints properly as 6" You **sure** about that? Did you try `print(Motifs[0], type(Motifs[0]))` and `print('AACGTA', type('AACGTA'))`?

Answer (score 1):

It's because `Motifs[0]` is also a list. You you could either do `k = len(stringlength[0])`, or you could modify `Modifs`:

```
Motifs = ['AACGTA', 'CCCGTT', 'CACCTT', 'GGATTA', 'TTCCGG']
```

Then it works.

Comment: Wow that worked, Thank you! I could have sworn that I tried k=len(Motifs[0]) directly and it didn't work, which is what led to so many print statements in the first place.

Comment: @user15910560 Np, glad I could help :)